# Creating a Materialized Path for a tree with SQL (Teradata)

Tags: sql, recursion, tree, teradata

I have an org tree given in a table, which is sorted "top-down" (from parent to child). The level of each instance is also given as an attribute. 
 data structure example:

| Index | Employee_name | Employee_level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Michael | 1 |
| 2 | Pam | 2 |
| 3 | Jim | 2 |
| 4 | Dwight | 3 |
| 5 | Angela | 1 |

In the above tree, Michael is the parent of  Pam and Jim, while Jim is the parent of Dwight. Angela is parallel to Michael with no children. 
I wish to create a column which would allow to query all the employees in a selected branch.
 After some reseach, I think that a Materialized path could work. therefore, I would probably need to create a column with the parent of each employee, and then have a recursion create another column with the desired key.
 Any ideas how to create this with Teradata SQL?
 Thanks

Comment: How do you know that *Jim* is the parent of Dwight and not *Pam*? Just based on the `Index`?

Comment: Yes, based on the index.

Comment: How big is this table? Is there a known maximum of levels?

Comment: about 6400 rows and 10 levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you the parent:

```
select t.*,
 (
   select max(index) 
   from tab as t2 
   where t2.index < t.index 
     and t2.Employee_level < t.Employee_level
 ) as parent_idx
from tab as t
```

When you materialize it in a table you can do simple recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 ( -- traverse the hierarchy and built the path
   SELECT idx, parent_idx, Employee_level, Employee_name
     ,Cast(Employee_name AS VARCHAR(500)) AS Path -- must be large enough for concatenating all levels
   FROM mytab
   WHERE Employee_level = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t.idx, t.parent_idx, t.Employee_level, t.Employee_name 
     ,cte.Path || ',' || Trim(t.Employee_name)   
   FROM cte JOIN mytab AS t
   ON cte.idx = t.parent_idx
)
select * from cte 
order by idx
;
```